# Abnormally large size of 'update.log' caused by error: "Cron readiness check failure"

Tags: upgrade, cron, magento2.3, log

I'm using `2.3`

one day my update.log will be `1gb` ago.

and i open this file showing this message.

how can i fix it,thank you!

> [2019-01-31 17:00:02] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure!
>   Found non-writable paths:     /public_html/.php_cs.dist
>     /public_html/.travis.yml    /public_html/CHANGELOG.md
>     /public_html/COPYING.txt    /public_html/Gruntfile.js.sample
>     /public_html/LICENSE.txt    /public_html/LICENSE_AFL.txt
>     /public_html/app/.htaccess  /public_html/app/autoload.php
>     /public_html/app/bootstrap.php  /public_html/app/functions.php
>     /public_html/auth.json.sample   /public_html/bin/.htaccess
>     /public_html/bin/magento    /public_html/dev/.htaccess
>     /public_html/dev/tests/acceptance/.htaccess.sample
>     /public_html/dev/tests/acceptance/composer.lock
>     /public_html/dev/tests/acceptance/tests      .......

i already ran this but can't help.

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
sudo chown -R :xxxx .
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, a cronjob can cause the problem.
Make sure that cronjob doesn't running from non-authorised user, which hasn't access to Magento's files.
By using this command you can display a list of the crobjobs by user, in this case `magento` is the username:

```
sudo crontab -l -u magento
```

To fix that, you can remove all the Magento's tasks from the list of cronjobs:

```
crontab -e
```

And installing them again:

```
bin/magento cron:install
```

Reference: https://digitalstartup.co.uk/t/how-to-diagnose-and-fix-ownerships-and-permission-issues/211